# What is the answer to this IQ test ?

Tags: visual

[image]
What is the answer for this IQ question. Please give an explaination.

Comment: *I'm putting this question on hold until proper attribution of its original source is provided.* —
It looks like you're asking us to solve a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, please **[provide attribution](/help/referencing)**. At minimum you need to let us know where this came from; any additional context you can provide is usually a big help to solvers. Posts which use someone else's content without disclosing where it came from are generally deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> The non-filled square with the plus sign above.

Explanation:

> The hatching in the upper middle field actually just hides a symbol that supposedly is there. From the visible symbols, one sees that the first row only consists of rectangles, the middle row of circles and the lower row of squares, so it has to be a square. Alternatively one can see that there's a plus sign in each row, so there should be one in the last row; both result in the same set of candidate symbols, which is further evidence that the selection is right. Finally, only the symbols on the diagonal are filled, so it must be the unfilled square.
>
>  BTW, the figure hidden under the hatched field is an unfilled rectangle with a small unfilled circle above it.

So, given that this as an IQ test question, what is my resulting IQ? :-)

Comment: Your IQ is one so far :) the question is not the entire test.

Comment: @Jasen I don't understand your remark. This is a great answer.

Comment: it was a response to the joke at the end.